# What are my options after receiving a visa refusal at the German embassy?

Tags: schengen, germany, visa-refusals

I and my wife applied for family visitor to Germany.but we got refusal with a reasons of letter and advise to appeal in Berlin Administrative Court. My brother-in-law adopted by a German citizen years ago. Now he is citizen of Germany. My wife already visited Germany in 2007. But at this stage we got refusal for the following reasons:

1. Your intention to leave territory of the Member states before the expiry of the visa could not be ascertained.
2. The financial capacity has not been proved adequately and proof of personal financial means for financing the stay has not been provided either.
3. You did not succeed to demonstrate your willingness to return to your  home county

However I am self-employed running a business of Travel agency and my wife is a teacher, and proper documents were attached with application. Now please suggest what should we do

Comment: Which boxes were checked? Their numbers. Apparently the translation(s) isn't coming through that well.